# How to set UITableViewCell height depending on device screen objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

Below is the code I had tried but it's not helpful please check.

```
static CGFloat cellDefaultHeight = 180;
CGFloat screenDefaultHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
CGFloat factor = cellDefaultHeight/screenDefaultHeight;
return factor * [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
```

Comment: You posted Objective-C code, not Swift code. Please tag properly.

Comment: yes your correct, but I can understand swift also, so if somebody can post swift code also @DharmeshKheni

Comment: what actually you want?

Comment: I'm given uitableviewcell height is 180, its a static height , But its looking good in IPhone7 and all except iphone5, so I need to set the height for all screen devices. @FaysalAhmed

Comment: The height is based on device or based on content of cell?

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height  
    return (cellDefaultHeight/screenDefaultHeight) * screenHeight
}
```

In **Objective C**

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       CGFloat screenDefaultHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
        CGFloat factor = cellDefaultHeight/screenDefaultHeight;
        return factor * [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method of `UITableView`.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its a logical error
Try this.

```
static CGFloat cellDefaultHeight = 180; //lets suppose its a defualt height for iphone6
CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
CGFloat factor = cellDefaultHeight * (screenHeight / 667) //667 is height of iphone 6
return factor * cellDefaultHeight;
```

Comment: So I have to give every device height replace with 667.